# jquery click to close current div using attr id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one problem with jquery secon click to close opened div.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/KVvrdy)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there are two button div with blue color.So  before clicked first button after click second button the first  `<div class="emoWrap" id="ac1">` is not closing.

I tryed the following js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".button", function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      var ID  = $(this).attr("id");
      $("#ac" + ID).toggleClass("emoWrap-active");
      /*var $current = $(this).find('.emoWrap').toggleClass("emoWrap-active");
      $('.emoWrap').not($current).removeClass('emoWrap-active');*/
   });
   $("body").click(function(){
         $(".emoWrap").removeClass("emoWrap-active");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="button" id="1">1</div>
   <div class="emoWrap" id="ac1">
      <div class="Emojis">For 1</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="button" id="2">2</div>
   <div class="emoWrap" id="ac2">
      <div class="Emojis">For 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the intended behavior that's not happening?

Comment: It works for me (if I correctly understand what your intended behavior is).

Comment: Looks like you are using jQuery already. Why not just use jQuery UI's accordion and style it as needed instead of reinventing the wheel for yourself?

Comment: @j08691 the problem will happen when you click after second button. The first opened div will be stay on there it needs to close when you click second button.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 the problem will happen when you click after second button. The first opened div will be stay on there it needs to close when you click second button.

Comment: @DevStud That is what happens for me.

Comment: @DevStud I think I understand what you want, I added an answer that reflects this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Goveav), I edited it so that all other emoWraps will turn off when a different one is clicked. This also means that it is exapandable, just change the `IDAmount` to the number of emoWraps you have.

This is the edited JavaScript code:

```
var IDAmount = 2;
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".button").on("click", function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      var ID  = $(this).attr("id");
      $("#ac" + ID).toggleClass("emoWrap-active");
      for(var i = IDAmount; i >= 1; i--){
         if(i != ID){
            $("#ac" + i).removeClass("emoWrap-active");
         }
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your interested and solved my problem. It is working and understandable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a bit more logic to your first function. This isn't how I'd do it, but building on your code would be something like:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var ID  = $(this).attr("id");

  if($("#ac" + ID).hasClass('emoWrap-active')) {
    $(".emoWrap").removeClass("emoWrap-active");
  } else {
    $(".emoWrap").removeClass("emoWrap-active");
    $("#ac" + ID).toggleClass("emoWrap-active");
  }
});
```

Like so: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMqZqY

Comment: Oh, I forgot it. Thank you sir.

Comment: now when i click second time it is not closing now ?

Comment: If you want that you're going to have to include more logic to test if it's already open or not. An easy option might be to just use jQueryUI, which has this "Accordion" feature built in.

Comment: i know jQueryUI's accourdion but it is not for this project.

Comment: @DevStud Updated my answer for you.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, didn't test. Although you do not need both clicks. You can remove from all the classes then just add the one you want:

```
  e.stopPropagation();
  var ID  = $(this).attr("id");
  $(".emoWrap").removeClass("emoWrap-active"); // Add this
  $("#ac" + ID).addClass("emoWrap-active");
```

Comment: did you tryed your solution ? Because it is not working.